# Calling functions from subdomain to main domain

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, vbulletin

I have a custom theme and use vbulletin at

public_html/

Wordpress is installed at a subdomain with files at

public_html/blog/

Ive read tutorials and a response from here that say to include the footer in the wp theme footer and I get this in the word press footer on home page.

```
{vb:raw ad_location.ad_footer_start}
{vb:raw ad_location.global_above_footer}
{vb:rawphrase contact_us}
{vb:raw vboptions.hometitle}
{vb:rawphrase admin}
{vb:rawphrase mod}
{vb:rawphrase archive}
{vb:raw template_hook.footer_links}
{vb:rawphrase privacy_statement}
{vb:rawphrase terms_of_service}
```

I did look at online tutorials and all talk about wanting to put the vbulletin inside the wordpress or gives some very basic design of putting a custom header and footer. This wont work as I'd like without retaining my original custom header and nav.

Another sample I followed was to create a php on your subdomain and include your original function file within it using a full path. This did nothing either.

How can I have the subdomain pull the files from the main domain?